# Using the "use a build subdirectory for output files' option in TeXMaker in combination with LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, texmaker, auxiliary-files, output, build-system

I want to use LuaLaTeX since I have some quite large .tikz files, but when I do so TeXMaker does not put the output files in the 'build' directory like it would do if I use PdfLaTeX. I find the build directory very convienent to keep things organized. Anybody any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 7):

The checkbox (Use a ‘build’ subdirectory for output files) in Texmaker adds the `-output-directory=build` parameter to the PdfLaTeX command.

As you want to use the same for LuaLaTeX you could try to add `-output-directory=build` manually to the LuaLaTeX command.